# update browser when leaving a team or deleting team with Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

since a a 26th June Microsoft Teams update, teams left by API are not updated in the browser, there are still in the browser.

Before the last update, it worked well

```
DELETE /groups/{id}/owners/{id}/$ref
DELETE /groups/{id}
DELETE /directory/deletedItems/{id}
```

But now, even though the group (team) is really left and deleted (and `GET /me/joinedTeams` returns 0), the team is still in the browser. It's look like the browser is no longer updated.

I tried to delete browser cache but with no success, old teams are still in the browser. I have to leave (or delete) manually the team in the UI, so it's not really good. But it worked well before 26th June, the team was automatically left in the browser when `DELETE /groups/{id}/owners/{id}/$ref` was called.

If someone knows how to deal with, I would really appreciate. Thanks

Comment: @Jorome, Thanks for reporting this issue. We have created a bug for this.